# Can a parameter in a method have no return?

Tags: c#

So I have this assignment for class and the professor is asking me to do a method that contains two parameters but no return and he also wants us to create another method with one parameter with no return.

Can somebody explain to me what he means by this?

[image]

Comment: yes, I do. I read through the textbook where it talks about method and parameters but  it does not talk about a parameter with no return.

Comment: It's best to ask your professor for help or clarification on things like this, because they can explain exactly what they mean. This also helps the professor know whether certain areas of their course might need more attention.

Comment: It's not the parameter that has a return, it's the method that has no return (it's called a void method). As Herohtar mentions, ask you professor for clarification. That's what they're there for!

Answer (score 1):

> Can a parameter in a method have no return?

No. You are misreading the assignment.  It is not: "(a method (with a parameter (that has no return)))".  It's "(a method (with a parameter) (that has no return))".  The "has no return" modifies "method", because methods are things that return. Parameters are not.

> Can somebody explain to me what he means by this?

He means:

- Make a method
- The method takes one parameter
- The method returns no value

I note that the question is somewhat ambiguous because it is legal in C# for a method with a regular body to have a *return type* but *no return statements*. Exercise: can you come up with such a method that is legal in C#?

Comment: Looking at the screenshot in the question, this does not seem to be where the misunderstanding is coming from, because the requirement is not stated in sentence form like that.

Comment: @Herohtar: Where exactly the original poster got this misunderstanding from, I do not know. But the question is plainly "Can a parameter in a method have no return?" implying that the original poster incorrectly believes that parameters, not methods are things with returns. Dispelling this incorrect belief is the first step in getting them back on track.

Comment: I think the images from my answer may explain where the misunderstanding is from.

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: rewritten the whole answer)*

[image]

[image]

The formatting in the assignment mislead you.

The four boxes in the table are independent.

Task 1. Create a method that meets the following criteria.

- Method Name: DisplayQuestionMessage
- Parameters:

  1. Whether the user's guess was correct: true or false
  2. The correct answer
- Return: None
- What the method does: This method will output 1 of 2 ...